# Bigcommerce - View who is Currently Signed-in

Tags: bigcommerce

**Scenario:** There is more than one person working on developing a Bigcommerce store. Is there a way to see if someone is logged in to prevent overwriting each other's work?

Thanks for looking and thanks in advance for an answer!

Comment: Bigcommerce offers client libraries, such as php, with which you can check if a session is active.

Comment: Are you looking to see if someone is making html/css/javascript changes within the control panel or through something like webdav as well?

Comment: What types of development? If just CSS, simply give each developer a separate CSS file to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

You can view successful admin log-ins by viewing the Store Logs area: 
your-domain.com/manage/settings/logs 
*However* you **cannot** view who is **actively** logged in.

There is no current way using the Bigcommerce API to check which backend users are currently logged in.

The only log feature Bigcommerce offers is a date/time log listing all backend logins, but it does not indicate who is *currently* logged in.

If building a solution for this was necessary, I would recommend using some sort of WebDriver to log into the store via the normal backend, and then parse the user log file to compare timestamps of the users logged in.

Your app logic would then compare the differences in timestamps for separate users.
Example: Parse all users who logged in within the last hour.
Assume that those users are actively logged in (again, there is no sure way of knowing who is actively logged in on the backend).